# finding time complexity of an algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I am trying to find big Theta of the following code:

```
k=0,x=0,y=0
for i=1 to 2n do:
    for j=0 to i^2 do:
        k+=1
    t=k
    while t>=0 do:
        ...(O(1) operations)
        t=t-0.5
```

I understand that the first loop always runs at O(n)
the second one is at most O((2n)^2) - when i=2n.
and that the while runs 2n^2 ( is this correct?)

so my calculation is : T(n) = O(n)*(O(n^2)+O(n^2)) = O(n^3)

I am not sure whether I am correct and how can I find now the big Omega - to show it is equal to the Big O.

Comment: Each loop is `O(i^2)` and the sum of `i^2` for `i from 1 to n` is `O(n^3)`

Comment: Big Omega is always equal to Big O when there is no other input involved (like an array of *n* input values or stream of randomly generated numbers), and thus every run will perform *exactly* the same operations.

Comment: @trincot this is not true, remember that Big O of N is a subset of Big O of N squared which is a subset of Big O of N to the power of 3... So its function is O(N^3) but O(N^5), too; but it is only Theta(N^3) and not Theta(N^5)

Comment: Yes, @Marco, that is true in the strict sense, but I don't think the assignment here was to use that interpretation of Big O, but as a "worst case" time complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can analyze the T(N) function. (For now I ignore the `while t>=0...` to be clearer)
We consider as the main operation this one: `k+=1` and we count how many times it is done. In math:

T(n) =

[image]

=

[image]

=

[image]

And this is a polynomial function which is [image] because we can find constants in order that the function is greater than n^3 and find others in order that is smaller than n^3.

Considering the `while t>=0` won't change the final result because it modifies only the constant factors

Comment: can you please clarify about the while loop, it's complexity is O(1) or is it indeed O(n^2))?

Comment: @Hawk_Y the while loop is O(n^2) as it will go from 0 to n^2 with a constant step.